# How can I get the highest sample rate historical heart rate data from health store?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am trying to get heart rate data from health store but when I make a query there are samples that come through with timestamps that shows that there are minutes that go by between the sample measurements. I remember watching an apple video where they were talking about the Quantity series and how these series have one kind of container for multiple data points of bpm data. I also see in the samples that there is a unit of " ___ counts per second" for each of the results so it would make sense if there were multiple datapoints within each of the results from the query but I don't know how to see what's inside of the results or if there is even anything more to them.

This is the code I am using to retrieve the data:

```
public func fetchLatestHeartRateSample(completion: @escaping (_ samples: [HKQuantitySample]?) -> Void) {

    /// Create sample type for the heart rate
    guard let sampleType = HKObjectType
      .quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else {
        completion(nil)
      return
    }

    /// Predicate for specifying start and end dates for the query
    let predicate = HKQuery
      .predicateForSamples(
        withStart: Date.distantPast,
        end: Date(),
        options: .strictEndDate)

    /// Set sorting by date.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(
      key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate,
      ascending: false)

    /// Create the query
    let query = HKSampleQuery(
      sampleType: sampleType,
      predicate: predicate,
      limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
      sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { ( _, results, error) in

      guard error == nil else {
        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
      }

      print(results ?? "Error printing results.")
    
      completion(results as? [HKQuantitySample])
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(query)
  }
```

Ultimately I want the most frequent heart rate data that is available. Ideally a bpm measurement every 5 - 10 seconds or less. Is this possible if I have not explicitly saved this heart rate data to the health store for a user before trying to access it or does Apple store all of this information in the health store regardless of the circumstances?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of rate data that is being used by HealthKit? My Apple Watch seems to report heart rate every 3 or 4 minutes; This is a trade-off between collecting data and battery life.  During a workout the watch will record heart rate data more frequently. Some other heart rate monitor may record at a higher rate, particularly if it is "actively monitoring" heart rate. Heart rates are reported in beats/min some averaging needs to be applied anyway, even if you do get rates reported more frequently.

Comment: It turns out you are correct! Although now another problem that I am having is that when I try to get data for the last 50 days for example, only ten days of heart rate data will be returned. Even if I make the query to healthKit in a loop with one query per iteration only the 10 most recent days that are queried will contain heart rate data. Any ideas why that would be? I can see in my health app on my phone that data exists for the days where no data was returned by health store.

Comment: A lot of promising advice if you do a search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HKSampleQuery+heart+rate

Comment: Thanks for the search but I didn't see any relevant information in the posts that are out there. I need high frequency historical data going back to the beginning of a users data history. I couldn't find anything on that.